# PHP Ajax Callback responseText Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

As I was coding I encountered an absolute annoying error when callbacking the responseText from PHP.

Now the issue is that, when I run the `fpass.php` file, and fill out the data, everything works except when callbacking the `responseText`, for example if it prints out `MAIN_FPASS_USER_NO_MATCH` from the PHP file it should change the `_('status').innerHTML` to a different text of my choice, and not what the PHP printed. Some ideas for what I missed in my code?

**JS Script:**

```
    function fpass(){
  var e = _("email").value;
  if(e == ""){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Type in your email address</br></br>";
  } else {
    _("fpassbtn").style.display = "none";
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "/fpass.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
        if(ajax.responseText == 'MAIN_FPASS_SUCCESS'){
          _("fpassform").innerHTML = '<h3>Step 2. Check your email inbox in a few minutes</h3><p>You can close this window or tab if you like.</p>';
        } else if(ajax.responseText == "MAIN_FPASS_USER_NO_MATCH"){
          _("fpassbtn").style.display = "none";
          _("status").innerHTML = "Sorry that email address is not in our system";
        } else if(ajax.responseText == "MAIN_FPASS_EMAIL_FAILURE"){
          _("fpassform").innerHTML = "Mail function failed to execute";
        } else if (ajax.responseText == "MAIN_FPASS_EXISTS") {
          _("fpassform").innerHTML = "already fpass";
        } else {
          _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
        }
          }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e);
  }
```

**JS Functions:**

```
// getElementById Function
    function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

// emptyElement Function
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
```

**Ajax Functions:**

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //x.send(data);
    return x;
}
// END Ajax Object

// Start Ajax Return
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<span id="status"></span>
<form id="fpassform" onsubmit="return false;">
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="88">
<button id="fpassbtn" onclick="fpass()">Reset</button></br>
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**
// AJAX CALLS THIS CODE TO EXECUTE

```
if(isset($_POST['e'])){
  include_once("vendor/db.php");
  $e = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['e']);
  $usql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
  $uresult = $mysqli->query($usql);
  $unumrows = $uresult->num_rows;
  if($unumrows == 1){
    $fpsql = "SELECT * FROM forgotpass WHERE useremail='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $fpresult = $mysqli->query($fpsql);
    $fpnumrows = $fpresult->num_rows;
    if($fpnumrows == 0) {
    if($fetch = $uresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $u = $fetch["username"];
      $e = $fetch['useremail'];
      $pn = $fetch['userphone'];

      $fpkey = substr(md5(uniqid($u)), 0, 14);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `forgotpass` (username,useremail,userphone,fpkey)
            VALUES ('$u','$e','$pn','$fpkey') ";
    if($mysqli->query($sql)) {

    $to = "$e";
    $from = "auto_responder@yoursite.com";
    $headers ="From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \n";
    $subject ="yoursite Temporary Password";
    $msg = 'MSG here';
    if(mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers)) {
      echo 'MAIN_FPASS_SUCCESS';
      exit();
    } else {
      echo 'MAIN_FPASS_MAIL_FAILURE';
      exit();
    }
    }
    }
  } else {
    echo 'MAIN_FPASS_EXISTS';
    exit();
  }
    } else {
        echo 'MAIN_FPASS_USER_NO_MATCH';
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Start with `console.log(ajax.responseText)`

Comment: Thanks in advantage @Marc B, but I did already know that :-)

Comment: Just prints `undefined` @u_mulder

Comment: Go further and output `ajax`

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to output `ajax`? You gotta be a bit more specific, I'm not really that used to JS @u_mulder

Comment: `if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) { console.log(ajax); `

Comment: Sorry @u_mulder but it does nothing when inserting `console.log(ajax);` at the start of `if(AjaxReturn(ajax) == true) { }` statement

Comment: @MarcB when using `PDO` statement instead of `mysqli` when users are logging in, the password verifier is invalid when fetching from `PDO`, but valid when fetching with `mysqli`, got any idea?